# Rogue Spry Menu

Tags: html, css, layout

Any idea's why my nav is showing up under the header and not inside next to the logo?

I spent all day yesterday designing a page just like this. Same everything on design and pretty much the same on coding,  except I used DW fixed pixel (or liquid, but i think fixed), but after seeing a course on Lynda.com I decided to redo it in DW's new fluid grid layout (which I love a lot more (never used before)).

I've tried several things (i.e logo image align left etc) to no avail.

**Screenshot**

[image]

*Comment* Entering inspect mode and resizing the header div shrinks the menu, so it know's it's in the header

P.S. Danko thanks for the screenshot assist. On allowing it to be posted.

Comment: Add code or add your website address.

Comment: It's difficult to debug without showing us some code of what you currently have/have tried. One thing to note is that an unordered list is a block level element so will automatically start on a new line - you could try applying a float:left to the ul

Comment: I figured the screenshot would be best so you have a visual of exactly what it's doing. I included a link to full size image since I don't have enough rep to post images but it was revised by a mod, my apologies

 <div id="header"><div id="logo"><img src="../images/logo.png" alt="BYR" width="96" height="79"/></div>
    <div id="menu"><ul id="MenuBar1" class="MenuBarHorizontal">
      <li><a href="#">Artists</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a class="MenuBarItemSubmenu" href="#">Get Signed</a>
      </li>
    </ul></div>

Comment: div's logo and menu were added post original posting.

CSS
#header {
 margin-bottom: 1em;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #ffcc00;
}

Comment: What CSS for div#logo and div#menu? Have you tried floating both left?

Comment: Yes when doing so it drops both out of the header and brings the bottom yellow border to the top. 

However, after reading your comment David I floated the header to the left and we're game. 

Sometimes it's the little things you forget about that take forever. lol. Thanks David.

Comment: " it drops both out of the header and bring the bottom yellow border to the top" You just need to apply an overflow:hidden to the div#header

Comment: Is that a better method than floating the header to the left? because after floating all 3 it fixed everything.

Comment: Have a read of http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Comment: I take that back after coming out of live I seethe menu is now out and snapped to the VERY top. Not sure if that's a problem as it snaps in in live view and on safari preview.

Thanks for the "read more".

Comment: By the way the overflow: hidden; fixed the last issue after removing the header float. 

Thanks again for all your time and help I really appreciate it, David.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered in comments. Credit goes to David Randall.

Added div's logo and menu to elements in header div per something I was going to try (floating left). While this brought them inline together it popped both out of header.

Dave suggested

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Worked perfect.